# Vertically integrating many mart files into a view in SAS

Tags: sas

I have a monthly file like ABCD_201310, ABCD_201311, etc...

These files all belong to the same mart, but I am trying to vertically integrate them with a SQL view. I attempted to

```
SELECT * FROM LIBPATH.ABCD_201310 UNION ALL SELECT * FROM LIBPATH.ABCD_201311
```

and I am getting a issue where the column type/format changes and the job fails.

Is there a better way to merge these into a non-materialized view?

Answer (score 0):

Two points:
One, I'd set them in the data step, it's much cleaner code.

```
data blah/view=blah;
set libpath.abcd_201310 libpath.abcd_201311 ... ;
run;
```

or

```
set libpath.abcd_201:; *everything starting with abcd_201;
```

or

```
set libpath.abcd_2013:;
```

etc.

Two, neither of these are going to deal well with type issues, but data step probably will be a little more comfortable with number of columns and order on the dataset at least.  There isn't a way in SAS to easily (ie, instantly and flexibly) deal with this.  The specifics for how to actually deal with it depend on your issue.  If you have one or two datasets that are 'bad' and the others identical, you can do specific recodes in the set statement.

```
data want/view=want;
set libpath.abcd_201310(rename=shouldbenumcol=shouldbenumcol_r) libpath.abcd_20311;
if not missing(shouldbenumcol_r) then shouldbenumcol=input(shouldbenumcol_r,BEST.);
run;
```

If it's a patten (ie, all datasets after a certain point have this problem) you could generate code to solve this more easily than typing it out.  You could also parse the contents of each table and figure out what columns will be problems.  It all depends on exactly what is wrong, and how flexible you need to be in the future (ie, if this is a production job that can't have attention every month but has a risk of a new problem every month, you have to be more careful; you might consider converting EVERYTHING to character with individual views, and then reconvert desired numerics back later).